# How to trigger Downstream job concurrently with different nodes(parameters) from upstream job from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

Here is the setup.

1. There is an upstream Jenkins job and a downstream Jenkins job.
2. The ask is to trigger the same Downstream job from the upstream job concurrently on multiple different nodes(nodes here are the parameters for this downstream job).

Tried the following:

1. Triggering downstream job from the same downstream job Jenkins UI by selecting multiple nodes is possible.
2. However, the task is to trigger the downstream job from upstream job UI. Tried using the option, "Trigger/Call builds on other projects." Under this menu, selected Add Parameters>NodeLabel parameter.
   For the label, I wanted to give 3 node names.
   How do we specify 3 node names here, for ex: node_test1, node_test2, node_test3?
   When I specify just 1 node, it triggers downstream job with that node, but not for more than 1 node. Tried comma separated node names, && separated, semi-colon separated, & separated.
3. Also, tried using the option, "Trigger/Call builds on other projects." Under this menu, selected Add ParameterFactories>All Nodes for Label Factory. Tried comma separated node names, && separated, semi-colon separated, & separated.

Appreciate any help, inputs.

Comment: The question is how do we specify the 3 nodes(parameters) in the upstream job?What is the format for that?

Comment: So basically you want to trigger a downstream job from and upstream job and pass 3 nodes as parameters. Then, the downstream job should run on any one of the 3 parameters?

Comment: No, the ask is to trigger the downstream job from upstream job and the downstream job should run on all the 3 nodes concurrently. The 3 nodes would be passed as parameters from the upstream job. So, the question is how do we accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using declarative pipelines?